# TextView stretches and pushes another view offscreen in horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 2 items: a `TextView` and a `RatingBar`. I want the `RatingBar` to always be directly to the right of the `TextView`. But I want the `TextView` to stretch as much as it needs until there is no more room, then I want it to add lines.

Here is a visual representation of How it should look, showing different widths of text:

```
| TextView - RatingView ------------- |

| TextViewTextView - RatingView ----- |

| TextViewTextViewTextVi - RatingView |
| ewTextViewTextView                  |
```

However, the `RatingBar` keeps getting pushed offscreen as the TextView stretches. This is what it does instead:

```
| TextView - RatingView ------------- |

| TextViewTextView - RatingView ----- |

| TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTex |
| tView                               |
```

Here's the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        style="@style/customRatingBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:isIndicator="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried adding `layout_weight` to either view or both. Can't seem to get anything to work. Should I use a `RelativeLayout` instead? I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a surprisingly difficult task! As @zimeriljazia suggests, making the `RatingBar` stick to the right and have the `TextView` wrap to the left is easy with a `RelativeLayout`, for the `TextView` just `alignParentRight` and for the RatingBar use `layout_toRightOf="@id/ratingbar"`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ratingBar1"
        android:text="@string/long" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you're just using the `RatingBar` for display (not for input) then you could use `TextView.setCompoundDrawables()` or one of its cousins. Send null for all but the right one, and for that set your rating image programmatically. You'll need to specify `layout_width` to be `wrap_content`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I ended up just going with the RelativeLayout and having the rating bar be stuck the right. Its not what the design shows, but thats the best I could do. If I get more time, i might try out your second suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! If you feel I answered your question go ahead and mark my reply as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 2 relative layouts one for the textview and one for the ratingbar.
Align the ratingbar layout to the right of the screen then make the textview layout android:layout_toLeftOf rating bar

Comment: Thats a good idea, but then the `RatingBar` would be stuck to the right of the screen. I want it to be stuck to the end of the `TextView`. (Until the `TextView` stretches too much)